# Display Child Page with custom fields within Parent Page

Tags: custom-field, page-template, advanced-custom-fields, child-pages

I have a parent page with multiple Child Pages.

On the child page template I have an include which has customfields. This works perfectly. The custom fields are on the child page in wordpress.

The custom fields are all within page-customfield-3.php and included in page.php to display them.

I included page-customfield-3.php within page-parent.php and it does not display the custom fields. I have included a link to a github gist with the code for each file as it is very long otherwise.

```
   CURRENTLY WORKING           
      Page.php
          |
Page-customfield-3.php 


 CURRENTLY NOT WORKING           
    Page-parent.php
          |
Page-customfield-3.php
```

https://gist.github.com/BHWD/9b30911c66337c5408e2

Comment: Please, post the relevant code in your question, not in external sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are putting the page result in $page. While the normal commands like the_title() and get_field() will look for the $post variable if  you are not setting a seperate ID of which you want the title.

I once did this by creating a backup of the $post variable, and then just put each post i wanted to include on the parent page in the $post variable. Then included the .php files, and every normal command like the_title(); & get_field(); works like it would normally would. But this is dirty, and there is probably a much better way to accomplish this.

You should probably just replace the main query with your get_posts query. Afterwards you should reset & restore the wp_query.

An other option would be to alter the page-customfield-3.php to include the $page variable you are setting in your page-parent.php.